# IShellLink: почему изменяются пути ярлыков?

Tags: c++, windows

Запускаю программу, оня меняет путь у ярлыков. Смотрю в свойствах, все ОК, поменялись. Проходит некоторое время, мин 20-30, пути изменились на старые значения.

Подскажите, в чем может быть причина? (проверялось на Win 7,8)

Answer (score 1):

КО сообщает: кто-то меняет их обратно. Это может быть вирус. Или антивирус (что порой одно и то же). Или это может быть скрипт, установленный системным администратором через групповую политику...

Попробовать выяснить причину можно с помощью программы [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо за совет, попробую так отследить. АВ нет, сторонних скриптов тоже нет, чистая виртуалка.